# The magic of Enumerator#feed

Tags: ruby

There is this [Enumerator#feed method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-feed), I discovered by accident. It is defined as:

> **feed obj → nil** 
>   Sets the value to be returned by the next yield inside e. If the value is not set, the yield returns nil. This value
>   is cleared after being yielded.

I studied the examples and thought »Yay!«, this should work using `feed`:

```
enum = ['cat', 'bird', 'goat'].each # creates an enumerator
enum.next #=> 'cat'
enum.feed 'dog'
enum.next #=> returns 'bird', but I expected 'dog'
```

But it does not work. I assume, it does not return `'dog'`, because `each` is not using `yield` internally.

The thing is, that I couldn't deduce any real world use cases from the given example in the documentation, Google is not a friend with this question, and (from what I've tried) `feed` seems not to work well with the other `Enumerator`/`Enumeration` methods.

Can you, please, give me a good example which explains `feed`, so I can get my head around it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def meth
 [1,2,3].each {|e| p yield(e)}
end

m = to_enum(:meth)
m.next #=> 1

m.feed "e"

m.next
#printed: "e"
#return => 2
```

***as you can see, feed affects the result of yield, BUT the enumerator 
method need to take care with it***

Now see the example of your owns:

```
a = ['cat', 'bird', 'goat']
m = a.to_enum(:map!)
m.next
m.feed("dog")
m.next
m.next
p a #=> ["dog", nil, "goat"]
```

*The way `feed` works:*

> first you need to call next then you call feed to set the value, and then the next call of next does apply the change (even if it raise an `StopIteration error`.)

For more explanation look at the thread here:[`Enum#feed:`](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4413849#1109566). This has the proper explanation about `enum#feed`.

Comment: Please include some context in the post. Answers on StackOverflow should not be "[barely more than a link to an external site](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion)"

Comment: @Gareth Is it ok? or more context I need to add? I think what I wrote there,is all about the `enum#feed`.

Comment: @Priti, I really like the `map!` example - thanks. Still hoping to get more answers with more examples. Currently, `feed` seems to be pretty useless in "the real world".

Comment: @tessi if you go through the Rubyforum post,you will get to know about `feed` more.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum, from the [current docs for Ruby v2.5](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-feed):

```
# Array#map passes the array's elements to "yield" and collects the
# results of "yield" as an array.
# Following example shows that "next" returns the passed elements and
# values passed to "feed" are collected as an array which can be
# obtained by StopIteration#result.
e = [1,2,3].map
p e.next           #=> 1
e.feed "a"
p e.next           #=> 2
e.feed "b"
p e.next           #=> 3
e.feed "c"
begin
  e.next
rescue StopIteration
  p $!.result      #=> ["a", "b", "c"]
end
```